# add a directory when creating tar archive

Tags: linux, bash, tar, create-directory

I want to tar some files (and directories) but want to create an additional directory those files should reside in.

So for example for the following directory structure:

```
myproject
  + file1
  + file2
  + subdir1
    + file3
```

I cd into the `myproject` directory and want to create the tar archive

```
tar czf myproject.tgz --place-into-dir myproject-1.0 file2 subdir1
```

to receive a tar archive with the following content:

```
myproject-1.0
  + file2
  + subdir1
    + file3
```

I am searching for an option like my fictional "--place-into-dir" above.
So the files should not be placed directly into the archive, but instead into an additional directory that is only created in the tar archive.

I want to avoid first creating that directory, copying all the files to that directory and then deleting them again only to create the tar archive.

Comment: Are you using `GNU tar`? Check output of `tar --version`?

Comment: @Inian Yes, it is GNU tar. Therefore the solution from kalj and Anton with `--transform` works. Thanks

Comment: @Inian I didn't try it, but your example doesn't do what I want. See the the answers of kalj and Anton.

Comment: Is there a solution when using bsdtar on a Mac? `$ tar --version` yields
`bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`.  `tar --help` doesn't yield anything obvious, so probably not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a directory on the fly inside the archive using  `--transform`:

```
tar czf myproject.tgz --transform 's,^,myproject-1.0/,' file2 subdir1
```

Comment: Certainly there should be a slash after directory name in the replace expression: 's,^,myproject-1.0/,'

Answer (score 5):

GNU tar has `--transform` option:

> ### `--transform=`*EXPRESSION*, `--xform=`*EXPRESSION*
>
> use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names

This should help you:

```
tar --transform 's/^myproject$/\0-1.0/' -czf myproject.tgz myproject
```